# Android always returns to first Activity when pressing Home after using Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP once from notification manager

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, android-notifications

I have a really annoying problem and I keep playing with all the flags/launchMode combinations without any luck. Hope somebody can help me :-)

In my android application I have to activities, A and B.

for the flow

> A -> B -> press Home -> returns to app

Activity B is displayed when the user returns which is just what I expect.

Now, I have a notification that would open Activity A no matter what the activities stack was before.

For that purpose, when invoking the intent from a notification I use

```
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
```

So now for the flow

```
A -> B -> press Home -> Receive a notification -> open it
```

Activity A is displayed, which is also what I expect.

The problem is that from this point forward (until I kill the application), if I return the first flow, activity A is always displayed even if activity B was top of the stack when I pressed Home...

I guess that since I gave Activity A the flag  `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP`, it keeps clearing the stack every time the application returns.

Is there any way to undo this flag setting or something, and keep both flows working as I expect?

Thanks,

Maxim

Comment: Gather some more info to help understand this. Go through your flow A->B->HOME->Notification->Open it. Then use ddms dump device state or `abd shell dumpsys` and have a look at the list of running tasks and the activities in them. How many tasks have you got? Which activities are running in which tasks? Post the output so we can see it.